# sorting a object list based on the one of its key : value pair in python and printing in html with key[value] in sorted

Tags: python

I am facing below issue, I have a object something like below
`

```
[
   {
     "":{
         "count":5201,
         "key":[
            "value1",
   },
   {
      "patient1":{
         "count":8,
         "key":[
            "value2"
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "+patient2":{
         "count":3,
         "key":[
            "value2"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

in the flask application on click on a button click, I am calling a function and trying to sort the above object named vs

```
def sortOnCount():
    vsObj = sorted(list(mongo.db.vn.references.vs.find({}, {'_id':0})), key=sort_key)
    print(vsObj)
#Able to print above vsObj- sample is provided above as object
    vsObj =sorted(vsObj, key=lambda x: x.count, reverse=True)
    print(vsObj)
    return ("nothing")
```

I am able to print 1st vsObj but after applying the sorted, I am getting issue

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'count'
```

Can someone please help me to find what is the issue?

Or even in html can I directly have a div which will be looping for on the object and sort on count value ?

I have tried above but getting

```
 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'count'
```

or can we directly do it in html itself using for loop and sorting on count key value pair while printing itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
    {
        "patient0":{
            "count":5201,
            "key":[
                "value1",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "patient1":{
            "count":8,
            "key":[
                "value2"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "+patient2":{
            "count":3,
            "key":[
                "value2"
            ]
        }
    }
]
data.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]["count"])
print(data)
data.sort(key=lambda x: list(x.values())[0]["count"], reverse=True)
print(data)
```

Here is the method to do it. I have sorted them with the value of key named 'count'. Also if you want to sort it descending then keep the reverse flag as True.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fN5fc.png)